# How can we update object of a particular object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```js
let items = state.refundHistory.items.map((o, idx) => {
  o.body.payment.loader = true;
  return o;
});
```

Now I want to update items available in state and want to return state with modified data.

Comment: What is the issue in the approach you have tried?

Comment: I have old items in state and want to add a key in items loader : true, then my items will be updated and i want to return state with new items which has loader key.

Comment: I meant, in your code that you have shared, is there an issue? You are using `.map` so you are returning new list. Try `.forEach` instead, if you wish to update same object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just reassign

```
let items = state.refundHistory.items.map((o, idx) => {
  o.body.payment.loader = true;
  return o;
});
state.refundHistory.items = items;
return state;
```

You could also handle this inline too

```
state.refundHistory.items = state.refundHistory.items.map((o, idx) => {
  o.body.payment.loader = true;
  return o;
});

return state;
```

However your better off using `.forEach`. This would save having to assign a new array.

```
state.refundHistory.items.forEach(item => {
  item.body.payment.loader = true;
});
return state;
```

Some libraries such as redux require you to create a whole new object in which case the spread operator is really handy

```
let items = state.refundHistory.items.map((o, idx) => {
  o.body.payment.loader = true;
  return o;
});

return {
  refundHistory : {
      items : items,
      ...state.refundHistory
  },
  ...state,
}
```

Comment: Nothing. I use `.forEach` all the time.

Comment: You have used `.map` and then setting new value. This is ideal situation for `.forEach`